# Show Image in a gridview column using MVCContrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display images(physically located in the Image folder of server and their paths are stored in db)in a column of a MVCContrib gridview.
I am using the following code but its returning only the image path,but I want to show the images in the grid column.

CODE

```
     <%=Html.Grid(Model.ImageGridView).Columns(columns=>{
     columns.For(x=>x.ImageID);
     columns.For(x=>x.ImageTitle);
     columns.For(x=>x.ImagePath);

 })%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a partial (`_Image.ascx`) that will be strongly typed to a string and contain the image:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" 
%>
<img src="<%= Model %>" alt="" />
```

and then:

```
<%= Html
    .Grid(Model.ImageGridView)
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.For(x => x.ImageID);
        columns.For(x => x.ImageTitle);
        columns.For(x => Html.Partial("_Image", x.ImagePath));
    }
) %>
```

Obviously if the `ImagePath` property is pointing to the physical location of the image on the server you cannot directly pass it to the `<img>` tag. You will need to convert it to a relative url. Ideally this should be done on the server before passing the model to the view.

Comment: Darin,I tried your code,but its giving error in the line <img src="Model" alt="" /> as File 'Model'not found.I am using the following syntax to store the image                             file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + obj.ImageID + "_" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName))); Pls help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my answer. It should be `<img src="<%= Model %>" alt="" />`.